# Can I use `pip` instead of `easy_install` for `python setup.py install` dependency resolution?

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

`python setup.py install` will automatically install packages listed in `requires=[]` using `easy_install`. How do I get it to use `pip` instead?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Yes you can. You can install a package from a tarball or a folder, on the web or your computer. For example:

#### Install from tarball on web

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.3.0.tar.gz
```

#### Install from local tarball

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.3.0.tar.gz
pip install requests-2.3.0.tar.gz
```

#### Install from local folder

```
tar -zxvf requests-2.3.0.tar.gz
cd requests-2.3.0
pip install .
```

You can delete the `requests-2.3.0` folder.

#### Install from local folder (editable mode)

```
pip install -e .
```

This installs the package in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/?highlight=editable#editable-installs). Any changes you make to the code will immediately apply across the system. This is useful if you are the package developer and want to test changes. It also means you can't delete the folder without breaking the install.

Comment: If you are used to using "python setup.py install" to install packages, it's natural to ask how to get "python setup.py install" to resolve dependencies with pip, but it's the wrong question. The solution is to install the package with pip and to stop using "setup.py install".

Comment: The problem @joeforker is you might be forced to do use easy_install if you do something like `python setup.py test`

Comment: @TomDotTom any idea on how to force to use pip when running `setup.py test`, please?

Comment: @joeforker, pip uses `setup.py` behind the scenes.  If I want people to be able to install my package with pip, I need to create a `setup.py` file.

Comment: If you want proof of this, try `pip install -e git+https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git#egg=Hello-World`.  The error is `No such file or directory: 'c:\python\src\Hello-World\setup.py`

Comment: @cowlinator the trick is to always execute setup.py with pip and never run it on its own. However projects like https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ make it possible to put everything in pyproject.toml and have no setup.py at all.

Answer (score 116):

You can `pip install` a file perhaps by `python setup.py sdist` first. You can also `pip install -e .` which is like `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone trying this: Note that `pip install -e` takes a directory as argument, not the `setup.py` file itself. At first I did not notice the period in `pip install -e .` which caused me some confusion :)

Comment: thanks, with `pip  install -e .` I can install but with pip, how I can uninstall from editable mode ?

Comment: Editable installs are uninstalled with a regular 'pip uninstall <package name>'

Comment: `pip install -e .` really is the answer. It support extras using `pip install -e .[extras]` and make distribute private python package in lab easier.

Answer (score 7):

If you are really set on using `python setup.py install` you could try something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install as InstallCommand


class Install(InstallCommand):
    """ Customized setuptools install command which uses pip. """

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import pip
        pip.main(['install', '.'])
        InstallCommand.run(self, *args, **kwargs)


setup(
    name='your_project',
    version='0.0.1a',
    cmdclass={
        'install': Install,
    },
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['simplejson']
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am facing to recursive callback using this method. when I am using 'python setup.py install', it will call  Install.run to call pip install ., this function will call Install. run again...