# PIP: Installing only the dependencies

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, distribute

I have a script that creates a `virtualenv`, installs `distribute` and `pip` in it and then optionally clones a `git` repo.

Now I have the project I will be working on, installed. But its dependencies are not installed. How can I make `pip` install all the dependencies as if I have issued a `pip install MyApp`?

**EDIT**: Appareantly my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependenc).

Not exactly sure but `pip install -e .` seems to do what I want without too many extra stuff lying around. I'd prefer if my code wasn't linked from `site-packages` though.

Comment: *I have a script that creates a virtualenv, installs distribute and pip in it (...)*. You know you can do all 3 things with `pip -E VENV_DIR pip` as pip by default installs pip and distribute in the newly created environment?

Comment: Cool tip! I don't use the mentioned script anymore though.

Comment: perhaps useful if you want to install only depedencies with pip using setup.py: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797124/how-to-use-setup-py-to-install-dependencies-only

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73376882/1601580

Comment: do `python setup.py egg_info;
pip install -r *.egg-info/requires.txt;
rm -rf *.egg-info/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my package root issuing `pip install -e .` installs dependencies.

Comment: That's some pretty serious side-effecting.  `-e` installs in editable mode, which means the package gets linked from site packages instead of copied.  I'd expect this approach to cause weird and subtle problems when you go and try to install the package for real, especially if you don't `pip uninstall` it first.

Comment: Note that this tries to install the package itself too in some way. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7218 for an example where this has unwanted effects.

Comment: this is obviously not the right answer! Why is this accepted? This will do much more than "only install dependencies".

Comment: @maciek since `pip` v21.3 editable installs when using [only] a `pyproject.toml` see: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#editable-installation

Comment: @CharlieParker while it doesn't answer the question, it solves the OP's problem

Answer (score 29):

If your dependencies are defined in the `setup.py` file, you can first dump them to an external file using:

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

This will list all your dependencies in `YOUR_PROJECT.egg-info/requires.txt` file. Then you can install them using `pip`:

```
pip install -r *.egg-info/requires.txt
```

to delete what you just created:

```
rm -rf *.egg-info/
```

to save some time copy pasting:

```
python setup.py egg_info
pip install -r *.egg-info/requires.txt
rm -rf *.egg-info/
```

Comment: this will not work if you have extra_require because the requires.txt will contain [dev]

Comment: If your setup.py has `extras_require` you may be able to `sed` out the extra lines before calling `pip install -r`

Comment: is there a way to skip dumping them into an external file? perhaps you should tell us too how to remove all the extra files etc that the first command you have does `python setup.py egg_info`.

Comment: +1 on the wild card to make the pip install work with everyone. Only missing the `rm -rf *.egg-info/` which I'd like to personally run to remove the dep file. fyi my answer inspired from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73376882/1601580

Comment: what if my dependencies are defined in `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: @jan-glx then create a wrapper `setup.py` with just `from setuptools import setup
setup()` and run the command. Make sure your `setuptools` and `pip` are updated

Comment: @KamilCuk @jan-glx If your project *only* contains a `pyproject.toml`, there is no need to create a temporary `setup.py` file. You can just call Python code directly, e.g. like `python -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup(script_args=["egg_info"])'` -- this is inevitably the same as what @KamilCuk suggested above.

Answer (score 5):

To install your project's dependencies (i.e. `install_requires` + `extra_requires`) you have to extract your dependencies using setuptools `egg-info` and then install the filtered list of the combined dependencies:

```sh
python setup.py egg_info
pip install `grep -v '^\[' *.egg-info/requires.txt`
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/) to create a `requirements.txt` that only contains the dependencies of your package:

```bash
$ pip-compile -o requirements.txt setup.py
```

Note that the command above only works if you do not already have a `requirements.txt` file. If you happen to have one already, just delete it.

Using the generated `requirements.txt` you can then run pip to install the dependencies:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

##### Bonus 1:

The `requirements.txt` will include comments that indicate where the regarding dependency originates from.

##### Bonus 2:

If you have have an `extras_require` section for optional dependencies in your `setup.py` that looks e.g. like this:

```py
    ...
    extras_require={
        "development": [
            "wheel",
            "debugpy",
            "pytest",
        ],
    },
    ...
```

You can create the `requirements.txt` including the optional dependencies by using:

```bash
$ pip-compile -o requirements.txt --extra development setup.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pip requirements file.

Essentially, place all your requirements, one in each line in a file and pass that to pip using the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

What more, if you have a standard environment, pip can actually dump such a file from existing installs using the command:

```
pip freeze
```

You can put the file thus generated directly into the pip requirements, and call the previous command from your deployment script.

Pretty cool, isnt it? :)

Comment: Cool, but it doesn't answer my question. I'm not looking for a way to define dependencies. Reading questions entirely and carefully helps goes a long way in providing correct answers.

Comment: Wait, You can put all your dependencies in a file and ask pip to install them all for you. Isn't that what you are looking for? If not, I didn't properly understand your question. Even now.

Comment: the difference being where the 'dependencies' are specified - in the requirements.txt (where you would specify "myrepo==1.0.1" or whatever) OR in the setup.py of the package in myrepo that you want to install.  if you've already got the repo in hand then only installing the dependencies might make sense.

Comment: @Tgr I don't think that is correct. I just used pip3 to install via a requirements file and several transitive dependencies were installed.

Comment: @dantiston this definitely [used to be a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110449/can-pip-install-packages-recursively-from-requirements-txt) some time ago. I have run into it with a recent version of pip as well, but it's entirely possible that that was some kind of user error on my side.

Comment: The question is asking for a way to install the dependencies of *the package being developed*. Its dependencies will be declared in the package's `setup.py` file. It could even have conditional dependencies (like based on OS). I don't think requirements.txt can handle that, but even if it can, you'd have to do some extra work to load the requirements into `setup.py` from the file.

Comment: This is not quite right, because `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` are for different purposes and their roles are not interchangeable. See Python packaging document: https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/#requirements-files