# Can pip install packages recursively from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I have a projectA that depends on other projects. Some of them also my projects from private git repository. I listed all dependencies of projectA in requirements.txt for all my packages.

Now projectB that projectA depends of have dependencies also (listed in requirements txt and setup.py), but pip doesn't install them when I'm running
pip install -r requirements.txt  for projectA.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the [documentation](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) says: "Requirement files are mostly flat. Maybe MyApp requires Framework, and Framework requires Library. I encourage you to still list all these in a single requirement file"

Comment: But then again, it seems I've learned something new: [recurusive requirements](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#recursive-requirements). [edit: note that this is for pip version 1.1.]

Comment: In general, the easiest way to write a `requirements.txt` file is to install all of the required things into a virtualenv, then run `pip freeze >requirements.txt`.

Comment: That's not convinient in my case, but thanks

Comment: Also, using recursive requirement files may eventually become a workaround for packages with dependencies outside PyPI. Such dependencies will continue to exist for various reasons, the least of which may be names already reserved on PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

[`snakebasket`](https://github.com/prezi/snakebasket) appears to be a wrapper of `pip` with exactly this design goal.

Comment: Just FYI snakebasket is not supported anymore and it's not compatible with the newest pip versions