# Install dependencies from pyproject.toml but not the package

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a python package that I want to install inside a docker file.

pyproject.toml looks like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "bar"
dependencies = [
    "pandas",
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
foo = [
    "matplotlib",
]
```

... and Dockerfile:

```
# ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install /app
```

This installs the dependencies (in this example, `pandas`) on every build, which I want to avoid to save developer time, since pyproject.toml is rarely touched.

**How can I install only `pandas` (the dependencies listed pyproject.toml) without having to `COPY .` and installing `bar`.**

I want to avoid:

- adopt other tools like poetry
- create a requirements.txt and use `dynamic` keyword in pyproject.toml, because I have `optional-dependencies` and I want to keep the list of dependencies as close together (i.e. same file) as possible.

Something like:

```
# ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./pyproject.toml /app/
RUN pip install --requirements-from /app/pyproject.toml  # <-- HERE
COPY . /app
RUN pip install /app  # <-- Installs `bar` only. All dependencies already installed.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317410/pip-installing-only-the-dependencies -- This question has already been asked, why is your question any different? -- Also maybe this has elements of answers: https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-install-only-dependencies-of-a-package/4027

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was searching for a solution that specifically uses pyproject.toml. They do mention pip-tools (`pip-compile -o requirements.txt pyproject.toml`), which I was not aware of, and may work for me. Will give it a try.

Comment: A problem with `pip-compile` as a solution is that by design it locks to an exact version, which may be a problem if the versions of python you are testing cannot all use the same exact version of some package.

Comment: I stumbled upon the exact same need with exactly the same list of 'avoid'. It seems to me that the feature proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440#issuecomment-1445119899) on `pypia/pip` would provide a solution.

Comment: Please voice your opinion and use case. Such a feature I would say is still on the table: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440