# Equivalent to `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt` for `pyproject.toml`?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Is there an equivalent `pip` command to install development dependencies (without installing the main project) if they are listed in (subgroups of) the `[project.optional-dependencies]` table of `pyproject.toml` instead of a separate `requirements-dev.txt` file?

Comment: AFAIK there're ways for `setup.py` but not for `pyproject.toml`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74354009/install-dependencies-from-pyproject-toml-but-not-the-package#comment135947494_74354009 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+only+package+without+dependencies

Comment: If you use [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install) as your frontend, you can use `poetry install --only dev`. But this currently only works if you _also_ use poetry as your build backend, since poetry doesn't yet support [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)

Comment: Please voice your opinion and use case. Such a feature I would say is still on the table: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440