# Default server in multiple server configuration of distutils in ~/.pypirc

Tags: python, distutils, pypi

I want to have multiple PyPI servers in my `~/.pypirc` file so I can easily publish to different servers, depending on the project.

My use-case is this, I have some internal projects that I want to publish to an internal PyPI server (`https://pypi.internal`), and I have some public projects that I want to publish to the public PyPI.

This is my current attempt, but it doesn't work. I want to default to `internal`, and be required to add the `-r pypi` (to the `setup.py` command) if I want to publish to the public server.

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    internal
    pypi

[internal]
repository: https://pypi.internal
username: brad

[pypi]
username: brad
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's strange that there isn't built-in support for setting a default, but here are two options which may help you work around it.

**Option 1:** Probably the simplest solution would be to leave your **~/.pypirc** script intact and create shell aliases for your internal and public uploads. This may give you more control over customizing things for your workflow.

Given this **.pypirc** file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    internal

[pypi]
repository: http://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: brad
password: <pass>

[internal]
repository: http://localhost:8080
username: brad
password: <pass>
```

Create some shell aliases (place these definitions in your shell's rcfile, e.g. **~/.bashrc**):

```
alias ppup_internal='python setup.py bdist_egg sdist upload -r internal'
alias ppup_public='python setup.py bdist_egg sdist upload'
```

Usage:

```
% ppup_internal
...
running upload
Submitting dist/foo-0.0.0.tar.gz to http://localhost:8080
Server response (200): OK
```

---

**Option 2:** A hack: you can work around the default by patching the default
repository name at the top of your setup.py scripts.

```
from distutils import config
config.PyPIRCCommand.DEFAULT_REPOSITORY = 'internal'
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    ...
```

Output:

```
% python setup.py sdist upload 
...
running upload
Submitting dist/foo-0.0.0.tar.gz to http://localhost:8080
Server response (200): OK

% python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
...
running upload
Submitting dist/foo-0.0.0.tar.gz to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

---

**Background:** If you define the **[distutils]** key in **.pypirc**, the upload command defaults to the **pypi url** when the **-r [repo]** argument is omitted.  The relevant code is in **distutils.config.PyPIRCCommand**:

```
class PyPIRCCommand(Command):

    DEFAULT_REPOSITORY = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi'

    def _read_pypirc(self):
        if os.path.exists(rc):
            self.announce('Using PyPI login from %s' % rc)
            repository = self.repository or self.DEFAULT_REPOSITORY
            realm = self.realm or self.DEFAULT_REALM
```

The old format of **.pypirc** expected a **[server-login]** section, which was far less flexible since it only defines a single target repository. This isn't a workable option since the **[pypi]** section below will be unusable:

```
[server-login]
repository: http://localhost:8080
username: brad
password: <pass>

[pypi]
repository: http://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: brad
password: <pass>
```

Now by default distutils will use this target:

```
% python setup.py sdist upload
...
running upload
Submitting dist/foo-0.0.0.tar.gz to http://localhost:8080
Server response (200): OK
```

But you can't access the any other repos: it silently defaults to the **[server-login]** properties:

```
% python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
...
running upload
Submitting dist/foo-0.0.0.tar.gz to http://localhost:8080
Server response (200): OK
```

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile on this one. It's very disappointing that it's not supported. `config.PyPIRCCommand.DEFAULT_REPOSITORY = 'internal'` is a bit confusing, does it refer to a section in `.pypirc`, or is it a URL to the server?

Comment: Yep, I thought it best to lay out all options I could find.  The string `internal` is the name of the section in the .pypirc which you want to be your default. So in your .pypirc you named your local repository `[internal]` so that line in setup.py will monkey-patch the default to be `internal`.

Comment: oops, I didn't realise I had to award the bounty separately, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem is when you want to have an internal PyPI package repository to install from. In this scenario using `pip install -e .` rather than `python setup.py develop` completely side-steps this problem. See [Can I use `pip` instead of `easy_install` for `python setup.py install` dependency resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/)