# How to install cpplint on windows?

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, cpplint

So I'm trying to get cpplint to work on Sublime Text 3 and I downloaded cppcheck and cpplint using the package installer on Sublime and now I'm trying to follow these instructions 
https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cpplint

I installed Python and I think I installed the get-pip since using the command prompt told me that pip is up to date but when I get to where it says run

```
[sudo] pip install cpplint
```

I'm lost.

I already put Python34 on my path and from my understanding, sudo is a Linux command that is the equivalent as runas in windows. I tried running this many different ways including typing in the complete path to cpplint. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip usually live in `C:\Python2x\Scripts`. You will need to add that to your path as well. Then you should be able to call pip from the command line. Just try opening `cmd.exe` and type pip and then enter. It should print out a bunch of helpful information about pip. If it just gives you an unrecognized command, then you probably added it to the path incorrectly.

You can also run pip like this:

```
c:\Python27\pip.exe install somePackage
```

If you're running cmd.exe as an admin user, this should work just fine. When I have downloaded a package that I want to install with pip, I usually open `cmd.exe` and then change directory to the file's location. So on your command line, you would do something like this:

```
cd c:\path\to\cpplint
```

Now that you're in the right location you can run `dir` to get a listing of what's in that folder. This is a good sanity check as sometimes when you unzip a package, there's a subfolder you need to navigate into to get at the `setup.py` script. If you see the setup.py, go up one level and do the following:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install -e directoryName
```

See [Can I use `pip` instead of `easy_install` for `python setup.py install` dependency resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen)

Alternatively, you can go into the folder with `setup.py` and just run the following, skipping pip entirely:

```
python setup.py install
```

Finally, you can also use pip to install from the zipped download:

```
pip install c:\path\to\zipped\package
```

See also:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html