# Python 2 & 3 compatible namespace modules (using pip)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

How is it possible build multiple python modules sharing the same namespace compatible for Python 2.7+ and 3.3+?

Let's call the namespace `test`. Now I want to have two seperate modules called `test.foo` and another one called `test.bar`. However, I'm currently developing `test.helloworld` which depends on both, `test.foo` and `test.bar`. Both are listed in the `requirements.txt` file.

The modules `test.foo` and `test.bar` are currently using the [Python 2 solution](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/#namespace-packages-today) for namespace packages:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Running the [suggested pip-command for development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen) `pip install -e .` turns into:  `ImportError: No module named 'test.helloworld'` while importing `test.foo` or `test.bar` is working.

The [Python 3 solution](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for namespace packages are *Implicit Namespace Packages* where the namespace package has no `__init__.py` file. This is sadly not working for Python 2 versions.

How can I design a solution for both Python 2 and 3 (which allows me to use `pip install -e .`)? The `--egg` solution does not work for me since it is already deprecated.

Comment: This should solve your query too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7075121/681481

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue, where I had to install a package for Python 2 and 3. I ended up having to download the code from GitHub, then ran the setup.py by calling

`sudo python setup.py install`

and

`sudo python3 setup.py install`

This results in the package being installed for both Python 2 and 3, even though the code itself was meant for Python 2. This allows me to work with the package whether I use Python 2 or 3, without any namespace conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use pkgutil-style namespace packages.

From https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/:

> #### pkgutil-style namespace packages
>
> Python 2.3 introduced the pkgutil module and the extend_path function. This can be used to declare namespace packages that need to be compatible with both Python 2.3+ and Python 3. This is the recommended approach for the highest level of compatibility.

A table listing out all the possible ways of dealing with namespace packages, and which ways would work together: https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/blob/master/table.md

Answer (score 0):

See the answer at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918246/why-does-setup-py-sweeps-the-content-of-the-namespace-before-installing/38919020#38919020) for complete instructions which works on both python 2 and 3.

In short, `setup.py` needs to have *unique* name for each module and a *common* `namespace_packages` definition in addition to `__init__.py` declaring the namespace set at `namespace_packages`.

If you are still having issues, please post your `setup.py` and `__init__.py` for each module.