# How to install wheels within setup.py

Tags: python, pypi, software-distribution

I'm creating a project that has dependencies on packages from PyPI. Namely :

```
['comtypes', 'docx', 'qrcode', 'PyPDF2', 'pyqtgraph', 'PyQt5', 'numpy', 'PIL','opencv-python']
```

However, some of these (for example `opencv-python`) only contain wheel files on PyPI. https://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv-python/

From my understanding, setuptools is not compatible with `.whl`. Is there any way to install the dependencies from a `setup.py`, ideally without the use of pip?

Answer (score 2):

Download the .whl file and run

```
pip install <directory>/xxxx.whl
```

on the terminal/cmd/powershell

Comment: I would ideally like this to be automated for a user how may not know how to install packages using pip, so I'm looking for alternative methods to this

Comment: did you ever figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem. The issue was that I was trying to use

```
python setup.py develop
```

to install the dependencies. When you use this command it attempts to use `easy-install` to install the dependencies, and if the dependencies are wheel files, it will fail.

We want to use `pip`, so try the following command in the directory in which your `setup.py` file is located

```
pip install .
```

Your `setup.py` structure doesn't even need to change! Hope this helps mate.

Inspiration/Ref: [easy_install tensorflow-gpu fails](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6540)

Same question (basically): [Can I use `pip` instead of `easy_install` for `python setup.py install` dependency resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen)

Comment: `pip install` throws this error `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`