# Can't install python module timeloop on OS X 10.3.7 with Python 2.7.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, module

I am using an old Mac Mini without internet connection, with OS X 10.3.7 and Python 2.7.7,
and cannot install timeloop with "python setup.py install".

Should timeloop principally work on this system?

Is there maybe any other way to get it work on this rather old machine?

Please don't recommend me to use a newer system: It's a project and I need to use this computer.

I would appreciate your help very much.

what I get is this: Do you see any error message which could help?

```
$ python setup.py install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing timeloop.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to timeloop.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to timeloop.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'timeloop.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'timeloop.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/timeloop
copying build/lib/timeloop/exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/timeloop
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/timeloop/exceptions.py to exceptions.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/EGG-INFO
copying timeloop.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/EGG-INFO
copying timeloop.egg-info/SOURCES.TXT -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/EGG-INFO
copying timeloop.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/EGG-INFO
copying timeloop.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/timeloop-1.0.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-ppc/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing timeloop-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timeloop-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
Copying timeloop-1.0.2-py2.7.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Removing timeloop 1.0 from easy-install.pth file
Adding timeloop 1.0.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timeloop-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for timeloop==1.0.2
Finished processing dependencies for timeloop==1.0.2
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about what's happening? What error do you get when you try and install timeloop? What version of timeloop do you have the setup for?

Comment: Thank you @Elenchus,

I have tried timeloop version 1.0.2 and 1.0.

I actually don't see a 'real' error message.
What I get is this: see above (the text was too long for the comment line)

Comment: I'm not familiar with installing packages this way; is the problem that all the dependencies are installed, but timeloop itself is not? You could try using pip instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen

Comment: I am having difficulties installing pip on this system as well. As still relatively new to Python I am not sure what the dependencies are for the timeloop module. Wouldn't have that given a real error message, if there was something missing?